# Tensorflow Multi-feature classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have the following type of data set. I want to classify the data whether Yes or No on the basis of multiple features i have.

X,Y,Z, Yes/No

7,50,4, Yes

4,20,3, No

8, 100,40, Yes

X,Y,Z - Features
Yes/No Desicion

I am **new** to tensorflow and machine learning and I also want to know which **classifier** to use.

Comment: Please refer to [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) before you want to ask Qs. This forum will help with specific code queries AFTER you have tried and researched ways on your own and are still stuck.

Answer (score 2):

What I will suggest is go through some of the basic lectures of Machine Learning like that of Andrew Ng [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning). 

Otherwise, just for making it work you can use tools provided by **Keras** so that you do not have to go through the complexity of Tensorflow. Keras can use both Theano and Tensorflow as backend. For your case, it will not matter much. Just go through how to use Keras API in python. And for your question of which classifier to use again depends upon how complex models you want to use. You can simply use Logistic regression and if you want more accurate model you can even use neural nets. Just go through some basic examples of how you can create models in Keras. Keras documentation is very good. You can directly look [here](https://keras.io/).